# Tough integral with coth[1/u]

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, hyperbolic-functions

I'm hoping to come up with an analytical solution for the following definite integral:

$$ \int_{-2/y}^{2/y} \cfrac{u}{\coth\left( \frac{1}{u}\right) - i \cot\left( \frac{z}{2} \right)} du$$

Here, $y$ and $z$ are strictly positive real constants. $i$ is the imaginary number $\sqrt{-1}$.

I tried doing this on Mathematica but it's been 20 minutes and it hasn't given me anything yet.  I was wondering if anybody had any tricks/tips for solving this integral?

Thanks!

EDIT: The imaginary component can be eliminated as follows:

$$ \int_{-2/y}^{2/y} \cfrac{u}{\coth\left( \frac{1}{u}\right) - i \cot\left( \frac{z}{2} \right)} du = \int_{-2/y}^{2/y} \cfrac{u\coth\left( \frac{1}{u}\right)}{\coth^2\left( \frac{1}{u}\right) + \cot^2\left( \frac{z}{2} \right)} du + i\int_{-2/y}^{2/y} \cfrac{u\cot\left( \frac{z}{2}\right)}{\coth^2\left( \frac{1}{u}\right) + \cot^2\left( \frac{z}{2} \right)} du$$
The second integral is odd, so it evalutes to zero.  Thus,
$$ \int_{-2/y}^{2/y} \cfrac{u}{\coth\left( \frac{1}{u}\right) - i \cot\left( \frac{z}{2} \right)} du = \int_{-2/y}^{2/y} \cfrac{u\coth\left( \frac{1}{u}\right)}{\coth^2\left( \frac{1}{u}\right) + \cot^2\left( \frac{z}{2} \right)} du $$
However, I don't think this is any easier to solve...

EDIT2: As noted by the comments, it might be a bit nicer if I set $b = 2/y$ and $c = \cot(z/2)$ so that my integral looks like:

$$ \int_{-b}^{b} \cfrac{u}{\coth\left( \frac{1}{u}\right) - i c} du = \int_{-b}^{b} \cfrac{u\coth\left( \frac{1}{u}\right)}{\coth^2\left( \frac{1}{u}\right) + c^2} du $$

Comment: Suggestion: Let $b = 2/y$ and $a = \cot^2(z/2)$. This cleans everything up a bit

Answer (score 0):

Hint

Try use the substitution
$$ I = \int\limits_{-2/y}^{2/y} {u\over\coth{1\over u} - i \cot{z\over2}}\ du =  -\int\limits_{-2/y}^{2/y} {u^3\over\coth{1\over u} - i \cot{z\over2}}\ d\left({1\over u}\right)$$
$$ =  -\int\limits_{-2/y}^{-0} {u^3\over\coth{1\over u} - i \cot{z\over2}}\ d\left({1\over u}\right) -\int\limits_{+0}^{2/y} {u^3\over\coth{1\over u} - i \cot{z\over2}}\ d\left({1\over u}\right) =  \int\limits_{-\infty}^{-y/2} {v^{-3}\over\coth{v} - i \cot{z\over2}}\ dv + \int\limits_{y/2}^{\infty} {v^{-3}\over\coth{v} - i \cot{z\over2}}\ dv.$$

Comment: Are you sure?  If I integrate the original integral numerically, I get pretty reasonable values.  I'm not sure if that substitution you did is valid since 1/u is not defined at 0, which is part of the original region of integration.  Also, the original integrand is well-defined everywhere -- the limit of the original integrand as u-->0 exists and is 0, according to Wolfram Alpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+as+x--%3E0+of+x%2F(coth(1%2Fx)-ic)

Comment: Also, you can see that your attempted numerical computation converges in the original form: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_(-1%2F2)%5E(1%2F2)+(v%2F(coth(1%2Fv)+-+i5))+dv.  This does help clarify why my earlier attempts in Mathematica were failing, however.  I had tried the same substitution and I had no idea why it was giving me the singularity error.  So thank you for that :)

Comment: Fixed, thanks. Will think more.